# Index of First Value Where Condition Not Met Numpy

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I have a 2D numpy array that looks akin to this:

```
np.array([
  [5, 4, 3, 2, 1], 
  [4, 3, 3, 3, 3],
  [4, 4, 2, 5, 1],
  [2, 2, 2, 2, 1] 
])
```

I want to find the index of the first value that violates a condition, and if they all satisfy the condition, return the `maximum index + 1`. For example, I want to find the first index where the condition `value >=3` is false.

- In `ls = [5,4,3,2,1]` it would be 3, as the
  first index where `value>=3` is false is `ls[3]` which has the value
  `2`.
- In `ls = [4,3,3,3,3]`, since all values in the list satisfy `value >=3`, return the max index +1, which is 5.
- For `ls= [4,4,2,5,1]` it would therefore be 2 since the first index
  that violates the condition is `ls[2]` which is the value `2`.
- For `ls= [2,2,2,2,1]` it would therefore be 0 since the first index
  that violates the condition is `ls[0]` which is the value `2`.

My current attempt applies my condition to create a boolean mask, then uses `np.argmin()` to find the index of the first `false` value

```
 np.apply_along_axis(
      lambda x: np.argmin(x>=3),
      1,
      np.array([
          [5, 4, 3, 2, 1], 
          [4, 3, 3, 3, 3],
          [4, 4, 3, 5, 1],
          [2, 2, 2, 2, 1] 
      ])
  )
```

But this outputs `array([3, 0, 2, 0])` since this method cannot handle the second case when all values in the array satisfy the condition. Is there a better approach? Please keep in mind this has to be applied to over a few thousand of these arrays so ideally complexity must be kept to a minimum.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's one way -

```
In [60]: a
Out[60]: 
array([[5, 4, 3, 2, 1],
       [4, 3, 3, 3, 3],
       [4, 4, 2, 5, 1],
       [2, 2, 2, 2, 1]])

In [61]: m = a<3

In [62]: np.where(m.any(1),m.argmax(1),a.shape[1])
Out[62]: array([3, 5, 2, 0])
```